# Getting files from subfolder

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, os.path

I'm pretty new to python, so please bear with me.
I'm trying to write a code that utilizes face-recognition, and with that i need to be able to access subfolders.

Currently i'm having issues with finding the folder "images". When executing the code, i'm in the folder `face-recognition` and need to access `images` that is one level under.

`- root`

`--- face-recognition`

`-- images`

```
def getImagePath():
    currentPath = os.path.dirname(__file__) # Absolute dir the script is in
    filepath = "../images/" # The path where the pictures are uploaded
    fileList = os.listdir(os.path.join(currentPath, filepath))
    return fileList;
```

Executing this code gives error `FileNotFoundError: [Errror 2] No such file or directory: '../images/'

Edit:
After trying to rewrite the code i saw what the actual problem is:

```
def getImages():
    currentPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)); # Absolute dir the script is in
    filepath = "../images/"; # The path where the pictures are uploaded
    directory = os.listdir(os.path.join(currentPath, filepath));
    images = [ fi for fi in directory if fi.endswith(('.JPG', '.jpg', 'jpeg', '.JPEG')) ];
    return images;
```

Running this code snippet trough the terminal on my mac works with no errors. But running the same code on the raspberry-pi 3, the error is thrown, and it does not make sens.

**Solution:**
While checking the images folder i found that i have a .gitkeep and .gitignore that ignores all files, (even .gitkeep), and that's why it threw an error because it removed the folder when cloning the repo on the raspberry pi.

Comment: Yes, and i found the problem, and it is not related to the code or python. Issue is i had a .gitignore file that ignored all files in the images folder (even the .gitkeep file), so when cloning the repo the images folder was removed

Answer (score 1):

Two parts to this:

1) You're going the wrong way. `../images/` goes up one directory. You just want `images/`. For absolute referencing you want `/face-recognition/images`

2) `glob` is your friend here https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

```
import glob 
file_list = glob.glob('/face-recognition/images/*.png')
```

or whatever extension you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\root
├───my
│   └───path
│       └───tmp.py
├───image
```

The [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module is handy (Python version 3.4+). For the directory structure above...

In tmp.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(__file__).parent
```

The image directory is under the parent of `tmp.py`'s parent.

```
>>> print(p)
C:\root\my\path
>>> print(p.parent.parent)
C:\root
>>> image_path = p.parent.parent / 'image'
>>> for img in image_path.iterdir():
...     print(img)

C:\root\image\empty.gif
C:\root\image\o.gif
C:\root\image\x.gif
>>>
>>> [str(img) for img in image_path.iterdir()]
['C:\\root\\image\\empty.gif', 'C:\\root\\image\\o.gif', 'C:\\root\\image\\x.gif']
>>>
```